# Indexer Issue - idle (741 in backlog)

Tags: magento2, cron, index

[image: **Some categories meta title & description is not setting.I am getting backlog in index status. any idea to fix this issue?**]

Some categories meta title & description is not setting.I am getting backlog in index status. any idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5):

You just need to reset your indexes status, remove missed cron jobs and remove the MView registers.

I use Magerun 2, you can do it via these commands:

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar && chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar && alias magerun2="./n98-magerun2.phar";
magerun2 db:query "DELETE from cron_schedule WHERE status='error' OR status='pending' OR status='missed'";
magerun2 index:reset;
```

To know the `_cl` tables that you have in your database you can run this command below.

```
magerun2 db:query "SHOW TABLES;" | grep _cl
```

Then you just need to clean up them.

```
TRUNCATE 'catalog_category_flat_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_category_product_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_data_exporter_products_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_product_attribute_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_product_category_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_product_flat_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalog_product_price_cl';
TRUNCATE 'cataloginventory_stock_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalogrule_product_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalogrule_rule_cl';
TRUNCATE 'catalogsearch_fulltext_cl';
TRUNCATE 'customer_dummy_cl';
TRUNCATE 'design_config_dummy_cl';
TRUNCATE 'elasticsuite_categories_fulltext_cl';
TRUNCATE 'elasticsuite_thesaurus_cl';
TRUNCATE 'inventory_cl';
TRUNCATE 'salesrule_rule_cl';
TRUNCATE 'targetrule_product_rule_cl';
TRUNCATE 'targetrule_rule_product_cl';

UPDATE `mview_state` SET `version_id` = '0';
```

And finish it running the reindex.

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento index:reindex;
```

Comment: @Rafael it worked super fine thanks for sharing this solution

Answer (score 2):

first run following command to reset the indexes

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalogrule_rule
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalogrule_product
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalogsearch_fulltext
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_category_product
php bin/magento indexer:reset customer_grid
php bin/magento indexer:reset design_config_grid
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_category
php bin/magento indexer:reset inventory
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_attribute
php bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_product_price
php bin/magento indexer:reset cataloginventory_stock
```

Than reindex all bove command one by one like this

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_product_price
```

Comment: it fixed by increasing inode limit

Comment: @PHPMagentoDeveloper can you explain a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with resetting indexer status with **php bin/magento indexer:reset** and rebuild the indices with **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**.

Comment: already tried but no luck